# how to store increasing number of columns in database tables

Tags: azure-table-storage

My application allows user to add new column from front end, how do I design my database table to store these kind of information.

I have already tried many websites but could not find any solution for the same.

Can anyone explain me with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check out the [Table Storage design guide](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/). Hopefully it helps.